# UDP broadcasts aren't being sent on specific occasions

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, broadcast

I've got this strange occurrence:

This is how I set up a UDP socket for broadcasting:

```
int broadcast_enable = 1;
int my_socket;

if ((my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR socket\n");
    return 0;
}

memset(&my_addr, '\0', sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
my_addr.sin_port = htons(20007);

setsockopt(my_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast_enable, sizeof(broadcast_enable));
```

This is how I send messages through this socket:

```
int len = sizeof(my_addr);
char buff;

buff = 'b';

if (sendto(my_socket, &buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, len) < 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR sendto\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I put WireShark on the sending computer and listened to the wifi interface.
1. When I connect to network 'A' I **can** see the messages being sent from the sender.
2. When I connect to network 'B' I **can't** see the messages being sent from the sender.

- Other broadcast messages are being sent and received in network 'B' (by other applications).
- The sender had static IP in network 'B'. I changed it to be non static and I saw the messages being sent. After a while I tried again and it didn't send the messages. I can't point on changes that occurred.

Does it rings a bell to anyone?
Please tell if you need any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using Wireshark wrong, e.g., looking at a wrong i/f or wrongly filtering the results.
Make sure you use it correctly, or better yet, try tcpdump to make sure your packets are indeed not being sent:

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -n udp
```

Comment: I have no filters while trying to see the packets. I'll try the `tcpdump` also

Comment: well, wireshark didn't show the real capture, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which interface to send the packet to. Broadcast packets are still sent to one interface only.

If I remember correctly, the default for 255.255.255.255 is the interface with the default route. If you use one of the subnet broadcast addresses on one of the interfaces, that interface is selected; alternatively, you can explicitly choose one via a socket option.